My code returns the same output (groupby sum and % of total) for different datasets?
So the database I'm working with is private, but it's made up out of data for farms the dataframe (I called it Pome) looks like this:

I want to input a new csv for every new commodity - as the file is filtered beforehand when downloading the primary data.
Then I want to group by 'B_Desc' column (The boundary of the farm description).
At the end I want the % each boundary uses of the total electricity.
Yet when I input the new CSV files (of a different commodity) my code returns the same group by sum and % of total.
Here is my code: (of course at the start I import pandas and numpy & read my csv file)
# Split the column into separate columns & new column names
Pome = Pome['Total Input Description;Primary Value;B_Desc;Boundary Value;UOM'].str.split(';', expand=True)
Pome.columns = ['Total Input Description', 'Primary Value', 'B_Desc', 'Boundary Value', 'UOM']


# Replace non-numeric values with NaN
Pome['Boundary Value'] = pd.to_numeric(Pome['Boundary Value'], errors='coerce')
# Replace NaN with a default value (e.g., 0)
Pome['Boundary Value'] = Pome['Boundary Value'].fillna(0)
# Convert to integers
Pome['Boundary Value'] = Pome['Boundary Value'].astype(int)

# Filter the DataFrame to include only rows with 'Total GRID Electricity' in 'Total Input Description'
pome_grid_electricity = Pome[Pome['Total Input Description'].str.contains('Total GRID Electricity', case=False)]

# Group the filtered DataFrame by 'B_Desc' and calculate the sum of 'Boundary Value'
sum_boundary_value = pome_grid_electricity.groupby('B_Desc')['Boundary Value'].sum().reset_index()

# Calculate the total of all groups
total_boundary_value = sum_boundary_value['Boundary Value'].sum()

# Calculate the percentage of each group relative to the total
sum_boundary_value['Percentage of Total'] = (sum_boundary_value['Boundary Value'] / total_boundary_value) * 100

# Rename the 'Boundary Value' column in the resulting DataFrame
sum_boundary_value = sum_boundary_value.rename(columns={'Boundary Value': 'Sum Boundary Value'})

# Print 
print(sum_boundary_value)

So I'm expecting different boundary totals & percentages when running different datasets, but it stays exactly the same.
Any feedback would be appreciated <3
